# Initialization of variables in a comprehension list

Tags: python

I´m quite new in python, and therefore a bit lost, I am trying to make a for loop in a more Pythonic way by doing the following:

```
result=[result +coefficient[j]*vector[j]for j in range(c)]
```

So I have a list of c coefficients and a list of c vectors and I want to add the product of them like the code aboce shows, for that, in a for loop I would start with an empty vector and add to that vector the rest of the terms, but in this way this is not working.

For instance, if the values are the following ones:

```
c=3 
coefficient =[ 1, 2,3] 
Vector=[[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]]
```

I should obtain :

```
result=[10,10,10]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the definitions of `coefficient`, `vector` and `c`. Or at least sample data that we can run. And an idea of the expected output.

Comment: They are just random ones

Comment: For instance:  c=3 coefficient =[ 1, 2,3] Vector=[[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]]

Comment: Please write the equivalent loop code to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why should the result be `[10, 10, 10]` and not `[9, 12 ,9]`?

Comment: 1*[3,3,3]+2*[2,2,2]+3*[1,1,1]=[10,10,10]

Comment: I am afraid it is not. ``1*[3,3,3]+2*[2,2,2]+3*[1,1,1] == [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`` and ``[sum(1*[3,3,3]), sum(2*[2,2,2]), sum(3*[1,1,1])] == [9, 12, 9]``

Answer (score 1):

Here the Pythonistic way with list comprehension:

```
>>> coefficient =[ 1, 2,3] 
>>> vector=[[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]]
>>> 
>>> vxc=[ [c*v_item for v_item in v] for (c,v) in zip(coefficient, vector)]
>>> print(vxc)
[[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [3, 3, 3]]
>>> 
>>> result=[ sum(x) for x in zip(*vxc) ]
>>> print(result)
[10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Notice than for `[9, 12, 9]` result  just `[ sum(c*v_item for v_item in v) for (c,v) in zip(coefficient, vector)]` expression.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly this should work:

```
result = [coefficient[j]*vector[j] for j in range(c)]
```

Comment: I don't get an Addition with that, so if my data are c=3 coefficient =[ 1, 2,3] Vector=[[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]] result should be result=[10,10,10]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
coefficients  = [1,4]
vector = [6,7]

result = [vector[j] * coefficients[j] for j in range(len(vector))]

print(result)
```

output

```
[6, 28]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that takes two steps:

```
coeff = [1,2,3]
vector = [[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]]

v_times_coeff = [ [coeff[i] * x for x in vector[i]] for i in range(3)]

answer = [ sum([x[i] for x in v_times_coeff ]) for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your operation is a matrix multiplication. This is easily done using the [`numpy`](https://www.numpy.org/) package:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([[3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1]])
result = a @ b
```

If you are using python version < 3.5 you have to use the [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) method:

```
result = np.matmul(a, b)
```